# Import a table from one user to another Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, import, export

Is it possible to import a table from one user to another from export dmp file in Oracle?

If yes, how to do it?

I have 2 users: MILLER and DUMMY. MILLER has table Planets. I've made export from MILLER (last.dmp) using Command Prompt, and I want to make **import** the table into DUMMY user from export file.

I have already tried use information from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-E9214ED5-0EE6-4D2B-8A9B-BA79572CED1D.htm#SUTIL1757) but it didn't help me.

I also can add log of command prompt, if necessary.

Comment: I think you're looking for the REMAP_SCHEMA option. [Find out more.](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-619809A6-1966-42D6-9ACC-A3E0ADC36523.htm#SUTIL927)

Comment: What utility did you use? `exp` or `expdp`?

Comment: I use exp and imp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the "Original Import" Utility, you should consider that:

- The user names must exist before the import operation; otherwise an error is returned.
- The IMP_FULL_DATABASE role is required to use this parameter. To import to a different schema than the one that originally contained the object, specify TOUSER.

More information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-98BA8BD2-DBA4-4201-B93B-4AC0AE91A107.htm#SUTIL1738)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all of you. Here is the solution:

1)grant IMP_FULL_DATABASE to DUMMY;

2)alter user DUMMY quota 50m on system; (because I had error 
IMP-00058: ORACLE error 1950 encountered

ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'SYSTEM'

Import terminated successfully with warnings.)

3)use FROMUSER and TOUSER in command prompt:

```
C:\>imp dummy@test3 fromuser=miller touser=dummy
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete process

Exporting:

```
expdp schema1/password dumpfile=Imported_Table1.dmp  directory=DIR tables=sourceTablename;
```

Importing:

```
impdp schema2/password DIRECTORY=DIR DUMPFILE=Imported_Table1.dmp 
remap_table=schema1.tablename:*destTablename*
remap_schema=schema1:schema2 TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=append;
```

*destTablename* -> Table name in destination schema. If table exists, system import the data otherwise system creates a new table with the data.

Ref: [TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-C9664F8C-19C5-4177-AC20-5682AEABA07F.htm#SUTIL936)

Addressed Issues:

> ORA-39002: invalid operation
>
> ORA-39166: Object schema2.tablename was not found or could not be
>   exported or imported.
>
> Table "schema2"."tablename" exists. All dependent metadata and data will be skipped due to table_exists_action of skip